# When opening a saved html page in browser how to make it to stop connecting to internet(server)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have saved web pages(example yahoo.com) to local file system. When opening it in browser(the URL looks like file:///home/.../*.html) the web page tries to connect to Internet(to download the ads, e.t.c). What has to be modified in the web page to stop it from connecting the Internet(server). I don't want to use ad-block add-ons for the browser, instead wish to change the web-page such that it should never try to connect to any server at all.

Comment: please provide your HTML sources of your saved webpages

Comment: http://in.yahoo.com/?p=us or just yahoo.com

Comment: So you had your browser open, on a page, and went to `File > Save As..` saved the page to your hard drive? And you want to open these pages in a browser locally but not have them access anything related to the server you essentially stole it from? Well.. without seeing your source code from your jacked pages, I would say start of by changing any URL's in the source code that aren't local to your computer.. example yahoo.com..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make it stop requesting external resources by removing references to external resources. There is no real flag or switch that handles this. The modern webpage is a very interconnected thing, loading data from lots of domains for all kinds of different reasons. (Google hosted JS frameworks, images from social networks, or images/css/js served from different CDN domains to speed up loading, etc.)

If you really need to do this, I would search the page for `"http"` and remove or alter the HTML element where it finds a match. Any reference to an external file should start with "http" so that should find them all.

In some cases you may be able to copy the resource from the external server and save it to a local file, then point the reference to a local relative url instead.

How to remove those reference without breaking the whole page, well that depends on a lot of things like what the resource is and what it's responsible for.  And that's impossible to advise on without the actual source of the page.

And it gets extra hairy with JavaScript. You may have JS that inserts images, for instance, and is hardcoded to load those form a specific domain. So now you have to edit that JS too to load local images instead.

So uh, yeah. Good luck.

---

Or perhaps you just want something like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to do it for you?

Comment: Maybe hes trying to make a Yahoo Clone.. :-)

Comment: I'm blindly answering the question from a purely technical point of view, because frankly, I'm afraid to know why.

Comment: I can understand that, its a train wreck, Im just watching cause I can't turn my head now..

Comment: @chris I am not trying to make a Yahoo clone. I save web pages for reading later to my usb drive while surfing from a browsing centre. My home network connection has a very limited bandwidth, so that i do not want the saved pages to consume all the bandwidth while i browse and read the saved pages simultaneously.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for the answer. I am not sure what you are afraid of. I was expecting an answer something like inserting some javascript code at the beginning of the saved webpages to make it not connect to external servers(something like returning fail to all the XMLHttpRequest()). I was just trying to learn javascript and looked at the fn XMLHttpRequest and thought that may be that is right way to go. But i have not mentioned this in the question because i do not want the bias the answers. Frankly i never expected -4 down votes :) . Closing the question is unbelivable.